# Label-Button is clickable outside of the texture

Tags: python, button, kivy, label

I created multiple label buttons. I gave each one "on_touch_up" attributes, with different functions. But when I click one label all functions are called. It seems to me that the clickable area is bigger than the texture of the actual label.
I tried to set the size of these Labels to different parameters like "texture_size" or "font_size" ,but without success.

Thanks for your help

```
<YearLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>

<YearScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,0.25
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba : 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 160,1565
            size: 419,60





    BoxLayout:
        id: years_layout
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: 0,-2825
        spacing: 380

        YearLabel:
            text: "2020"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2020()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2021"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2021()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2022"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2022()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2023"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2023()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2024"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2024()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2025"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2025()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2026"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2026()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2027"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2027()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2028"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2028()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2029"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2029()
        YearLabel:
            text: "2030"
            font_size: "150sp"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_touch_up:
                root.to_2030()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kivy the touch events are propagated to all the children. You need to limit it to the respective widget by using `collide_point`. Below is example of the `on_touch_up` function correct definition:

```
            on_touch_up:
                self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and root.to_2020()
```

Similarly, you can define for rest of the labels.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that did not worked for me

Comment: Sorry, please check the updated answer. It should be combined with and so that the ```root.to_2020()``` function is nested under the ```collide_point``` method.

Comment: I thought I fixed the problem, but I hadn't. Your solution works. Thank you